# How to remove an Item from an Mongodb array documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following mongodb collection named Posts with document like following:

```
{
    "_id" : "111",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "replyPost" : "aaaa",
            "username" : "John Doe"
        },
        {
            "replyPost" : "bbbb",
            "username" : "Jane Smith"
        },
        {
            "replyPost" : "cccc",
            "username" : "Jane Smith"
        },
        {
            "replyPost" : "dddd",
            "username" : "Jane Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to remove an array item with the replyPost: "cccc" so the result would be:

```
{
    "_id" : "111",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "replyPost" : "aaaa",
            "username" : "John Doe"
        },
        {
            "replyPost" : "bbbb",
            "username" : "Jane Smith"
        },
        {
            "replyPost" : "dddd",
            "username" : "Jane Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried .update method with $pull refering to mongodb document
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
Posts.update(
  {_id: this._id},
  { $pull: { comments: { replyPost:"cccc"} } }
);
```

which don't seem to be working.  can anyone see the problem?

Comment: I have checked and query works fine in mongoshell

Answer (score 0):

See if you're getting the right _id. It's in string format.

I tried the same in mongo shell. It worked for me.

Here's the log:

```
> db.posts.insert({
...     "_id" : "111",
...     "comments" : [
...         {
...             "replyPost" : "aaaa",
...             "username" : "John Doe"
...         },
...         {
...             "replyPost" : "bbbb",
...             "username" : "Jane Smith"
...         },
...         {
...             "replyPost" : "cccc",
...             "username" : "Jane Smith"
...         },
...         {
...             "replyPost" : "dddd",
...             "username" : "Jane Smith"
...         }
...     ]
... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.posts.update({_id:'111'},{$pull:{comments:{replyPost:'cccc'}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.posts.findOne()
{
        "_id" : "111",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "replyPost" : "aaaa",
                        "username" : "John Doe"
                },
                {
                        "replyPost" : "bbbb",
                        "username" : "Jane Smith"
                },
                {
                        "replyPost" : "dddd",
                        "username" : "Jane Smith"
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose, you can do:

```
db.posts.remove({replyPost: 'cccc'}, function(err) {
})
```

The first parameter can be any mongoose query expression. All matches will be removed from db.

See [mongoose remove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Comment: This query does nothing, if you mean ``db.posts.remove({"comments.replyPost": 'cccc'}, function(err) {
})`` it will remove whole document, not only a single comment.

Answer (score 0):

Tested Works Fine:

```
Posts.update((
  {"_id" : "111"},
  { $pull: {comments: {"replyPost" : "cccc"}} },
  { multi: true }
)
```